# How long could effectively message stay in Message broker Q

Tags: jms, persistence, message-queue, amqp, middleware

I plan to have persistent message Queues based on some implementation of AMQP and JMS API. I would like to know whether is ok (from architectural point of view) to have messages staying in the queues for hours. A day is max.

I plan to use the message broker as another persistence layer basically. Is this viable?

The technologies that I am evaluating are ActiveMQ, RabbitMQ or qupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I plan to use the message broker as another persistence layer
>   basically. Is this viable?

The broker's persistence mechanism for message retention is usually file-based, or JDBC; either one will work. It is viable? Sure, its a feature of the broker, nothing wrong with using it for the intended purpose, assuming temporary message retention is your goal; 1 day is not a big deal.

But if you're planning to retain messages for 1 day, or more, I recommend doing some calculations based on average message size and total messages per day that *may* end up sitting in a queue. Queue depth, by default, is usually a low number, like 10Mb, and if exceeded, the broker will probably drop subsequent messages; you want to prevent this from happening. Vendors handle this differently, so check with RabbitMq and ActiveMQ for specifics and what configuration parameters are used to control depth. I know SonicMq has what's known as the "DeadMessage" queue, a destination for expired or undeliverable messages; other products might have something similar.

Answer (score 1):

It's OK to have persistent queues, and it's OK if messages are hanging around in the queues: Clients might be disconnected because of updates, network problems etc. That's one benefit of queues to decouple sender from receiver, and the queue is the buffer. However these use cases are not the normal mode of operation, it's rather an exceptional situation.

Using a messaging broker as "another persistence layer" is technically speaking possible, but in this case a database is probably more suitable, because *quick message delivery/messaging* and *long term storage/database* are different tools/scenarios. So ask yourself the question: Is it still messaging or is it already a database?

If in your use case the normal message delay (= period between sending and reception) is always beyond an hour, a database might be better, because *JMS selectors* are normally slower and less comfortable than database queries using *where clauses*.

There is another aspect: Consider the need for an online backup of your messages in a JMS provider, especially in a HA cluster mode. It might be easier to do this using a database.

Comment: Note that a server running a message broker (such as RabbitMQ) with PERSISTENT messages, is in fact a database server and you should plan it accordingly. For instance, if you use a virtualized server, make sure that it uses a local hard drive for the persistent message store because the I/O load will be similar to that of a database server.